# Directly altering/editing a sound file

Tags: pro-tools, logic

I used to record music utilizing Adobe Audition. Although the program was rather limited in its earlier versions, it had one knockout feature that I absolutely loved! I had the ability to edit my sound file manually. If I played too loudly in one part, I could manually adjust the volume, or lower it if required, I could select places to silence the audio file, such as while taking a breath etc.

I'm currently using Logic Pro X and I have not found a way to be able to do this yet. I also have Pro Tools 11, but have not yet learned how to use it.

Does anyone know if there is a way to alter the volume levels of particular parts of a sound file within either Logic Pro X or Pro Tools 11? Is there a plug in that I can purchase that does this?

I have a bass track that I recorded, that was a very good performance, but I was playing a bit too dynamically, and my bass amp is not very good, so I don't foresee myself producing a bass track with much better quality. If I could go in and manually edit the volume on certain parts, I think it would sound phenomenal.

Let me know if there are any plug-ins or built in features in Logic Pro X or Pro Tools 11 where I can do this. My other option is to export the bass file and import it into my Windows pc and mix it down in Adobe Audition, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

In Adobe Audition, I was able to double click on a soundfile and highlight sections of the soundwave and manually increase or decrease virtually any section of the file. It was very easy to identify the peaks and shrink them by a few db by simply highlighting the peak right clicking, and selection volume cut, and manually inputting the amount to cut by. Is there any similar plug in or feature in another program?

Comment: Have you looked at the manual of logic x? This is basic functionality... Search for 'volume' or 'automation'.

Comment: How/why are you using 3 DAWs without trying to learn the basic functionalities? It's clip gain, gain, volume automation, trim, analog channel in ProTools.

Comment: 3 DAWS - Adobe Audition is what I started with several years ago. I no longer use it. Logic Pro X - I just got it 2-3 months ago, and found it more user friendly than Pro Tools. Pro Tools - industry standard if you read my post, I clearly specify that I have not yet used PT. I think it is a good tool to learn, and I do not think my next computer will be a mac, therefore, I will have to learn a DAW that is cross-platform, unlike Logic. I have learned the basic functions. I tried the automation on Logic Pro X and all that gives me is a line that I can set points on. It will probably serve

Comment: the same purpose, but in a much less intuitive way. I would like to manually shrink the wave file in the peak points by hand. I do not want to have to set a line and lower it, because it's much less accurate and requires a lot more  fiddling around. I understand that directly editing the sound file is 'destructive', but I know exactly what I need to do to the file to make it sound better, and I have not found the way to do it in Logic Pro X. In Adobe Audition it's very intuitive and easy to do, so I simply wanted to know whether there was a way to do it in Logic or Pro Tools.

Comment: As I said before, I have not yet learned Pro Tools, and just wanted to know if there was an easy way to do this as a sort of heads up.

Comment: Can you add to your question a little more about what the Adobe function was and how it worked?  Did you just highlight a section of the audio file and click and drag up or down?  What about automation is it that you don't find good enough?  Is it just too tedious, or are you not getting the outcome that you're looking for?  Have you tried compression to even out the dynamics?  I do have a solution in mind that would be relatively similar to what you're describing but a little background info will help me put together a better answer.

Comment: in ProTools there is a pencil tool for you to draw on the waveforms. It was commonly used to fix spikes and loud transients before, but with the plugins that are available these days, I don't know if many people still use it.
You know you're probably better off asking such questions in the respective DAW's forum.

Comment: @takuya - there is a DAW forum?  Or are they forums specific to each DAW?

Comment: @Basstickler They all have their specific forums. Within those forums, they do also talk about other DAWs.

Comment: Basstickler, I have added the revision to my post.

Comment: @takuya - I think I was misunderstanding.  Are you referring to forums outside of Stack Exchange?  I thought you were suggesting that there were SE Forums for DAWs but I haven't been able to find any.

Comment: @Basstickler yes, forum outside SE. DUC for ProTools duc.avid.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a regular pro-tools user, but a universal way I'd approach this in any DAW is to:

1. Open a new project with the sample in question.
2. Create an automation for the volume of the sample.
3. Add control points to the automation as required.
4. Render the stem to another sample. This could be achieved by simply rendering the project.

Optionally you can skip the new project and rendering steps and just keep the automation on the original audio clip in the original project.

Answer (score 0):

On Pro Tools you can use the Trim plug in to alter the gain throughout the duration of the track. You can automate it so it rises and falls where you want it to. It is adviseable to record it right in the first place but if you need to there is this as an option on pro tools. I'm not sure if there is something similar on Logic, I'm sure there is, any plug in where you can automate the gain of the track should surfice

Neil
www.aaasounddesign.com

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for "Clip Gain" in ProTools.  Any clip can have the volume raised or lowered without using automation.  I like it because it's be insert so you can level your audio out before it  hits compressors or fx.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to edit specific sections of volume manually, Pro Tools has a relatively simple way to do this. All versions of Pro Tools have a dropdown on each audio track in the editing window that allows you to view waveforms, volume, and pan. The dropdown defaults to waveforms. You'll need to create a new session and import the audio file that you'd like to edit. Create a track to pull that file onto. Once you've created the track you'll see the dropdown labeled waveforms. Clicking that will display the other available view options. Choose Volume which will display the waveforms with an opaque overlay and line covering them.  In this view you can now edit your volume by selecting sections and click/dragging that line up or down or creating your own markers individually to drag the volume line up or down. No plugin needed. This is basically writing the track volume automation manually. When you play back the file it will follow the edits you've made.